# How do I Find an empty area in a bitmap image

Tags: android, android-bitmap

How can I detect empty area in bitmap.
in the `imageView` there is a bitmap. I get it use `getbitmap()` method. it is `.png` format and one part of image is empty.

Is there any way to detect that area?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Is it transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your `Bitmap` as `bitmap`

```
 int color = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
```

If `color = 0`,  It is `transparent`.

else It is `Opaque`.

Comment: I should search every pixel of bitmap?

Comment: searching every pixel take time and it is slow

Comment: Ideally you would be interested if some specific point in the image is transparent, that said if you have TouchEvent you can get X,Y coordinates from it and pass into `getPixel` method

Comment: thanks. I have touch event but I want to define it before touch. now i think find another way.

Comment: Let me know more about your requirement, I would try to help

Comment: I want to find transparent area. but you know that it is slow. so I decided to find center of a bitmap. because this empty area is near the center.

Comment: although it is not exact area but I think is better that finding by searching every pixel.

Comment: Yes indeed, it would be better

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int transparency = ((bitmap.getPixel(x,y) & 0xff000000) >> 24);
```

This should give you the level of `transparency` of the pixel in `coordinates(x,y)`.

The value of `transparency` will be  between `0` and `255`, when `0` is completely transparent and `255` is completely opaque.